# Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read Magento System Requirements

Tags: magento2, php, error, magento-community, installation

I'm getting this error after uploading to webserver.

I have **PHP 5.5.33** which it clearly says should work on the requirements page it links to... and I just spent the last 8 hours waiting for the whole package to upload.

Any idea what's going on? I'm using the community version.

Comment: Please, upgrade your PHP version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

never trust Magento manuals...
in fact neither code not updated for new wiki version, and wiki not updated for latest stack. 
and PHP 5.5 is unsupported now, even no security patches

magento code:

```
/* PHP version validation */
if (!defined('PHP_VERSION_ID') || !(PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && PHP_VERSION_ID < 50700 || PHP_VERSION_ID === 70002 || PHP_VERSION_ID === 70004 || PHP_VERSION_ID >= 70006)) {
    if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
        echo 'Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later. ' .
            'Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html';
    } else {
        echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <p>Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read
    <a target="_blank" href="http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html">
    Magento System Requirements</a>.
</div>
HTML;
    }
    exit(1);
}
```

system req:

```
PHP

5.6.x
5.5.x, where x is 22 or greater
7.0.2–7.0.6 except for 7.0.5 (supported by Magento version 2.0.1 and later only)

There is a known PHP 7.0.5 issue that affects our code compiler; to avoid the issue, do not use PHP 7.0.5.
```